# AngularJS and Bootstrap, data-toggle and data-target

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I`m using Modals from Bootstrap and AngularJS but I want only toggle the modal if userInfo.info.dogeAddress is not '';

```
<a ng-class="{notClickable: userInfo.info.dogeAddress == '', clickable: userInfo.info.dogeAddress != ''}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Opwaaderen &raquo;</a>
```

so, I know how to do it with classes, but how can we do this with data-target and data-toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but probably you should eat the ng-click event before it ever reaches to bootstrap.

Such as:

```
<a ng-click="userInfo.info.dogeAddress == '' && $event.preventDefault()" 
   ng-class="{notClickable:  userInfo.info.dogeAddress == '', clickable: userInfo.info.dogeAddress != ''}" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Opwaaderen &raquo;</a>
```